# Installing matplotlib on OS X 10.9.1

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have installed Homebrew, Xcode and all the necessary tools but when I executed this command on the terminal: brew install matplotlib 
The following error occurred after installation

1 warning and 1 error generated.

error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

---

Cleaning up...
Command /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/g7/nt2vgm9x0wv_r0pz6sm_18y00000gn/T/pip_build_Joshua/matplotlib/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/g7/nt2vgm9x0wv_r0pz6sm_18y00000gn/T/pip-OxzEFW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/g7/nt2vgm9x0wv_r0pz6sm_18y00000gn/T/pip_build_Joshua/matplotlib
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Joshua/.pip/pip.log

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? The matplotlib does not work on my python script file.

Answer (score 0):

1) Do you have any errors if you run `brew doctor`?

2) If you have a **brewed** Python installed, you should be using the **brewed** `pip` to install matplotlib. ie. `pip install matplotlib`

Comment: @Williams, when I run brew doctor, this is what I get


Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/de
    /usr/local/share/man/de/man1

Comment: I tried pip install matplotlib, the same error occurs

Comment: can we see the last few lines of the pip.log?